# Doctrine only inserts one record after foreach loop

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4, entitymanager

I have a simple array with some values that need to be inserted into the DB. Out of all the values only the last one is actually inserted.

When I put the `flush();` inside the loop, records do get inserted.

When I dump the entity manager before the flush (outside the foreach) I do see references to all the values (entities).

Though, only the last record is inserted. It does get id #3, so it seems the other ones are lost somewhere.

```php
    $values = [
        "val1", "val2", "val3"
    ];

    foreach ($values as $value) {
      $i = new MyEntityClass();
      $i->setVerified(false);
      $i->setName($value);
      $this->em->persist($i);
    }
    $this->em->flush();
```

Update:
I hooked up a eventlistener to pre and post flush.

```php
  public function preFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $args) {
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();

    foreach ($em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
      dump($entity->getName());
    }
  }

  public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args) {
    dd($args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions());
  }
```

In the preFlush all values are clearly printed and the postFlush dump is empty.

Update 2:
I'm using a uuid_binary_ordered_time as follows

```
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="uuid_binary_ordered_time", unique=true)
   * @GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
   * @CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidOrderedTimeGenerator")
   * @Groups({"uuid"})
   */
  protected $id;
```

Using `10.4.8-MariaDB` and  `php v7.3.10`

**Update 3:**
I'm still trying to figure this out and and now have a different scenario, but am still running into the problem that multiple actions are not executed. Might this be DB configuration related instead of Doctrine?

Case: Gather data from table A and table B, insert data into Table C, delete record from table A.

By following the suggestion from @Jakumi (or looking into the logs) I can see the following queries being executed (spoiler, the row in table A is deleted, but there's no new row in table C):

```
"queries": {
  "1": {
    "sql": "SELECT t0.email AS email_1, t0.status AS status_2, t0.payment_provider_id AS payment_provider_id_3, t0.payment_method AS payment_method_4, t0.quantity AS quantity_5, t0.price_total AS price_total_6, t0.created_on AS created_on_7, t0.updated_on AS updated_on_8, t0.paid_on AS paid_on_9, t0.id AS id_10, t0.s_uuid AS s_uuid_11, t0.product_id AS product_id_12 FROM payment_pending t0 WHERE t0.payment_provider_id = ? LIMIT 1",
    "params": [
      "tr_S432rV6fhM"
    ],
    "types": [
      "string"
    ],
    "executionMS": 0.0005559921264648438
  },
  "2": {
    "sql": "SELECT t0.username AS username_1, t0.roles AS roles_2, t0.password AS password_3, t0.email AS email_4, t0.email_verified AS email_verified_5, t0.created_on AS created_on_6, t0.registration_method AS registration_method_7, t0.has_premium AS has_premium_8, t0.premium_until AS premium_until_9, t0.verified_mobile AS verified_mobile_10, t0.active AS active_11, t0.facebook_id AS facebook_id_12, t0.google_id AS google_id_13, t0.id AS id_14, t0.s_uuid AS s_uuid_15, t16.is_a AS is_a_17, t16.wants_a AS wants_a_18, t16.firstname AS firstname_19, t16.lastname AS lastname_20, t16.screen_name AS screen_name_21, t16.function_title AS function_title_22, t16.mobile_number AS mobile_number_23, t16.birthday AS birthday_24, t16.age AS age_25, t16.zipcode AS zipcode_26, t16.city AS city_27, t16.id AS id_28, t16.s_uuid AS s_uuid_29, t16.user_id AS user_id_30 FROM user t0 LEFT JOIN user_extra t16 ON t16.user_id = t0.id WHERE t0.email = ? LIMIT 1",
    "params": [
      "some@email.com"
    ],
    "types": [
      "string"
    ],
    "executionMS": 0.0007460117340087891
  },
  "3": {
    "sql": "\"START TRANSACTION\"",
    "params": null,
    "types": null,
    "executionMS": 0.00010800361633300781
  },
  "4": {
    "sql": "INSERT INTO user_payments (status, payment_provider_id, payment_method, quantity, price_total, created_on, updated_on, paid_on, id, s_uuid, user_id, product_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    "params": {
      "1": "open",
      "2": "tr_S432rV6fhM",
      "3": "paypal",
      "4": 1,
      "5": "17.95",
      "6": "2019-10-24T07:27:22+00:00",
      "7": null,
      "8": null,
      "9": "9dd4af76-f630-11e9-90f2-024216133c1a",
      "10": "9dd4af76-f630-11e9-90f2-024216133c1a",
      "11": "c2abb28c-f62f-11e9-b71f-024216133c1a",
      "12": "bce559e8-f5bc-11e9-85f8-024216133c1a"
    },
    "types": {
      "1": "string",
      "2": "string",
      "3": "string",
      "4": "integer",
      "5": "decimal",
      "6": "datetime",
      "7": "datetime",
      "8": "datetime",
      "9": "uuid_binary_ordered_time",
      "10": "uuid",
      "11": "uuid_binary_ordered_time",
      "12": "uuid_binary_ordered_time"
    },
    "executionMS": 0.0003437995910644531
  },
  "5": {
    "sql": "DELETE FROM payment_pending WHERE id = ?",
    "params": [
      "b836c012-f62f-11e9-80b0-024216133c1a"
    ],
    "types": [
      "uuid_binary_ordered_time"
    ],
    "executionMS": 0.0003409385681152344
  },
  "6": {
    "sql": "\"COMMIT\"",
    "params": null,
    "types": null,
    "executionMS": 0.09281802177429199
  }
},
"enabled": true,
"start": 1571902427.83485,
"currentQuery": 6
```

Comment: what is the id generator for your entity? maybe the last one overwrites the former ones?

Comment: @Jakumi Thanks for your reply, I updated the question. I'm using uuid_binary_ordered_time.

Comment: this might be a very weird idea, but ... how did you get your first entity into the database? If it was done in the same symfony installation, have you tried adding a second entity in the same way? because it shouldn't work, since the "clone" is essentially just a new entity, so it shouldn't work either. also, does your entity have any relations to other entities? and if so, please post their definitions (both sides). also have a careful look into the profiler and see what database queries are run.

Comment: @Jakumi this is purely a Command script that inserts the records into the database. For testing purposes i've dropped the entire DB multiple times, made new migration scripts, etc. There are no relations set on the table or entity. Entity class was made trough Symfony maker-bundle (make:entity). I don't really understand what you mean with the ' shouldnt work ' part though.. In every loop a new entity is created and persisted in the entity manager. These should have different references, so it should work?!

Comment: oh, I ... confused this question with a different one. sorry ;o( your case is actually so weird, that it's hard to find an entry point. can you find out which queries actually get executed, perhaps via: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/155/how-to-get-doctrine-query-stats-information-in-symfony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not exactly sure what caused this, but I did manage to 'solve' the issue. I did so by completely removing MariaDB, its components and the database itself from my dev environment.

After re-installing MariaDB, running mysql_secure_installation, re-creating the database and running migrations, all works as expected.

`$this->em->flush();` outside the foreach now inserts all records and same goes for my second problem case.

Comment: same thing happening here. I feel like we shouldnt have to hack something that should just work. Tried rebuilding my docker environment but it doesnt seem to have helped

Comment: scratch that, my looping structure was wrong!! fine now

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use the flush immediately after the persist like this:

```
$values = [
    "val1", "val2", "val3"
];

foreach ($values as $value) {
  $i = new MyEntityClass();
  $i->setVerified(false);
  $i->setName($value);
  $this->em->persist($i);
  $this->em->flush();
}
```

or better:

```
public function save(MyEntityClass $myEntityClass): void
{
    $this->em->persist($myEntityClass);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

in the entity's repository and use it when you want to save the related entity individually

**EDIT - Another way to try**

```
$values = [
    "val1", "val2", "val3"
];

$this->em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

foreach ($values as $value) {
  $i = new MyEntityClass();
  $i->setVerified(false);
  $i->setName($value);
  $this->em->persist($i);
}

try {
    $this->em->flush();
    $this->em->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->em->getConnection()->rollback();
    $this->em->close();
    throw $e;
}
```

also add row in definition of $id:

```
/**
* @var \Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface
*
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(type="uuid_binary_ordered_time", unique=true)
* @GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
* @CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidOrderedTimeGenerator")
* @Groups({"uuid"})
*/
protected $id;
```

**EDIT - Use type="uuid"**

update the declaration of $id

```
/**
 * Entity constructor.
 *
 * @param UuidInterface|null $uuid
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function __construct(UuidInterface $uuid = null)
{
    if (null === $uuid) {
        $uuid = Uuid::uuid4();
    }
    $this->id = $uuid;

    [Other fields ...]
}

 /**
 * @var \Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @return UuidInterface|null
 */
public function getId(): ?UuidInterface
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

doing so you should exclude that it is $id to mess with Doctrine ... and we can investigate elsewhere

Comment: Because in the case of N records that would result in N insert queries. When flushing after N persist it should be 1 insert query for all persisted entities.

Comment: @Svdb it depends a lot on how the entity is set and the various relationships it can have, certainly there is something irregular in the transactions

I updated the code above, try it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your 2nd method, with ``` beginTransaction() commit() and rollback() ``` and the result unfortunately stays the same.

What did you mean by 'add row in definition of $id' ? To add the @var definition?

Comment: yes, i mean to add the @var but at this point I don't think it solves the problem ...

do you have any entity subscriptions?

Comment: I have one preFlush listener, though disabling that one doesn't make any difference. Here's the code anyway
``` 
$em = $args->getEntityManager();
foreach ($em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
  if (property_exists($entity, 's_uuid') && $entity->s_uuid === null)
    $entity->s_uuid = $entity->getId()->toString();
}
```

Comment: ok, you can do another test. ( otherwise we wait for someone to give us a hand : -) ). 
Use type "uuid" instead of "uuid_binary_ordered_time", update the code in the post above

Comment: I must admit, you are pretty darn creative in finding different ways to do this :) Though unfortunately I must report that it did not change the outcome.

Comment: damn, i was hoping the problem was in the generation of the Id ... I am waiting for someone to solve because in the past I also had several similar problems and I always try to understand more.